# 99% on the first epoch: overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation, overfitting

I am working with time-series data and I am trying to classify the Fault happening in the system. The problem is no matter what I try so far, I get 99.79 validation accuracy on the very first epoch. It changes to 99.90 after couple of training runs but nevertheless, it's too good to be true. I have tried the KFold approach and custom metrics (F1) but result is still the same. I also use SMOTE to balance out the dataset, as one of the classes (0) is too prevailing compared to other ones (1 and 2).

My main function:

```
output_nfs = data_normalization(nf_data.iloc[:, 1:28], 'PCA') #Normalization via StandardScaler
output_afs = data_normalization(af_data.iloc[:, 1:28], 'PCA') 
output_nfs ['Fault'] = nf_data['Fault'].values
output_afs ['Fault'] = af_data['Fault'].values

output_nfs_rec_array = output_nfs.to_records (index = False)
output_afs_rec_array = output_afs.to_records (index = False)

final_data = np.concatenate ([output_nfs_rec_array, output_afs_rec_array])
np.random.shuffle(final_data)
y=final_data ['Fault'] #target
X=rf.drop_fields(final_data, ['Fault'], False).view (np.float64).reshape(len(final_data), len(final_data.dtype)-1) #Actual datapoints
y_new = [] #Combine all the faults into 3 separate categories: no faults (0), electrical (1), mechanical (2)
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i]==0:
        y_new.append(0)
    elif (y[i] == 188)|(y[i] ==176)|(y[i] == 315)|(y[i] == 485)|(y[i] == 286)|(y[i] ==707)|\
         (y[i] == 959)|(y[i] ==958)|(y[i] ==817)|(y[i] == 187)|(y[i] == 489)|(y[i] == 632)|\
         (y[i] == 102)|(y[i] ==648)|(y[i] ==687)|(y[i] == 935)|(y[i] == 332)|(y[i] == 846)|\
         (y[i] == 944)|(y[i] == 254)|(y[i] == 181)|(y[i] == 317):
        y_new.append(1) #electrical
    elif (y[i]==604)|(y[i]==603)|(y[i]==958)|(y[i]==154)|(y[i]==162)|\
         (y[i]==165)|(y[i]==512)|(y[i]==948)|(y[i]==151)|(y[i]==163)|(y[i]==296)|\
         (y[i]==734)|(y[i]==844)|(y[i]==191)|(y[i]==560)|(y[i]==297)|(y[i]==504)|(y[i]==735):
        y_new.append(2) #mechanical
y = y_new  
y=np.array(y,dtype=int)

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
n_folds = 10
kfold = KFold(n_folds, True, 1)
scores, members = list(), list()


import keras_metrics as km
from keras.layers import Dropout
labels = ['no faults', 'electrical fault', 'mechanical fault']
def evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    trainy_enc=to_categorical(y_train)
    testy_enc=to_categorical(y_test)
    early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)
    model = Sequential()
    n_cols = X_train.shape[1]
    model.add (Dense (35, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (n_cols,))) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add (Dense (10, activation = 'relu')) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add (Dense (3, activation = 'softmax'))
    model.compile (loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['acc'])
    model.fit (X_train, trainy_enc, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, epochs= 100, 
               validation_data=(X_test,testy_enc), callbacks = [early_stopping_monitor], verbose = 1)
    # evaluate the model
    _, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, testy_enc, verbose=1)

    return model, test_acc

for train_iX, test_iX in kfold.split(X):
    X_train, y_train = X[train_iX], y[train_iX]
    X_test, y_test = X[test_iX], y[test_iX]
    #Class imbalance is too severe. No Fault prevails. Using smote to balance out electrical and mechanical faults
    from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
    sm = SMOTE (random_state = 12)
    X_train,y_train = sm.fit_resample(X_train,y_train)
    X_train, y_train = utils.shuffle(X_train, y_train, random_state=42)
    X_train, X_test = feature_selection (X_train, X_test, None, 'PCA', None)
    model, test_acc = evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
    scores.append(test_acc)
    members.append(model)
```

My PCA function is the following:

```
pca = PCA (0.95)
pca.fit(X_train)
X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train)     
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)
return X_train_pca, X_test_pca
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't think that the model is overfitting? It just seems very odd that I get almost one at the very first epoch. Several posts have indicated that this is an overfitting issue.

Comment: I see your point. I honestly doubt that I should be hitting 99% on my validation set immediately. But thank you for the input. Any suggestions for what to look for in data to check for overfitting issue?

Answer (score 3):

"Too good to be true" is not the definition of overfitting. I am not saying you are not overfitting, but that you do not have to. For example, if you trained a classifier to detect if written text is in English or Chinese, you would very fast get >99% accuracy because this would be a very simple problem. On another hand, there are problems where you would never reach 70%.

As about your problem, you said that you have time series data and you are using $k$-fold cross validation. This means that *likely you may be overfitting* because using such way of validating the results, you potentially leaking information from the future into your training set. This is *not* how you validate time-series. Instead you should split your data in such way that you [train on the past and test on the future data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350655/leave-one-out-cross-validation-for-lstm/351765#351765).

Comment: Thank you. I am using TimeSeriesSplit from sklearn and unfortunately, face different sort of problems right now. But I appreciate your input.