# Stock Price Neural Network Optimization

Tags: regression, neural-networks

I have seen quite a few people create Neural Networks to predict stock prices, so I decided to try my hand at it. I am using an LSTM network, and have had decent results. But I am worried about overfitting. I have tried to limit this as much as I know how, but I am still not sure if it is an issue in my current network.

```
'''

Model_Input = Input(shape=(5, 1), name='Model_Input')
x = LSTM(50, name='Model_0')(Model_Input)
x = Dropout(0.5, name='Model_dropout_0')(x)
x = Dense(64, name='Dense_0')(x)
x = Activation('sigmoid', name='Sigmoid_0')(x)
x = Dense(1, name='Dense_1')(x)
x = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='lecun_normal', activation='linear')(x)
Model_Output = Activation('linear', name='Linear_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=Model_Input, outputs=Model_Output)
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')
# Gives the input data a new shape of (1259, 5, 1)
Normalized_Input_Data = np.reshape(Normalized_Input_Data, Normalized_Input_Data.shape + (1,))
# Extract just the closing price from the data (open, high, low, close, and volume are contained)
Normalized_Closing_Price = Normalized_Input_Data[:,3]

# Train neural network
history = model.fit(x=Normalized_Input_Data, y=Normalized_Closing_Price, batch_size=10, epochs=500, 
shuffle=True, validation_split=0.25) 

'''
```

The input data is a little over the past 5 years worth of stock data. I only get the data daily. At the time of writing this, I think the network sees 1273 days worth of data instead of 1259. I am using 25% of the data for validation. I figured this would be enough, but it may not be. The below images are for the Nvidia stock.

[image: Here is the networks output for Nvidia's stock. The red and blue moving averages are only there for visuals.]

[image: Here is the loss an val_loss for the network. It is zoomed in to the first corner since they both flatten out after.]

So over the first 5-6 epochs the loss changes drastically, after it seems to level out and stay pretty consistent. I am not sure if the loss is even enough to worry about, or if there is a way to make it better. Also any changes or suggestions for the network architecture are welcomed.

**EDITED**

So after changing the training and validation data, changed the model architecture to keep it from overfitting (as much as I could anyway).

```
'''
    # Concluded that the first dropout layer(s) needed to be more harsh than 
    # the later ones
    Model_Input = Input(shape=(5, 1), name='Model_Input')
    x = LSTM(64, name='Model_0')(Model_Input)
    x = Dropout(0.5, name='Model_dropout_0')(x)
    x = Dense(64, name='Dense_0')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.1, name='Model_dropout_1')(x)
    x = Activation('sigmoid', name='Sigmoid_0')(x)
    x = Dense(1, name='Dense_1')(x)
    Model_Output = Activation('linear', name='Linear_output')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=Model_Input, outputs=Model_Output)
    adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')
    # Implemented early stopping to keep the epochs from creating overfitting
    Early_Stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', mode='min', patience=50, verbose=1)
    history = model.fit(x=History_Input_Data, y=History_Closing_Price, batch_size=128, epochs=750, shuffle=False, validation_data=(Validation_Input_Data, Validation_Closing_Price), callbacks=[Early_Stopping])
'''
```

For those who might need it, I split the input data up before feeding it to the model.

```
'''
    # Split the dataset up into training and validation datasets
    # Use the first 75% of data to train on (This is the oldest data)
    # Use the last 25% of data to validate on (This is the most current data)
    Length_Of_Data = len(Normalized_Input_Data)
    Validation_Length = int(Length_Of_Data * 0.25)
    History_Length = (Length_Of_Data - Validation_Length)
    
    # 956 days worth of data for network to train on
    History_Data = Normalized_Input_Data[:History_Length]
    
    # 318 days worth of data (most current dates) to be validated on
    Validation_Data = Normalized_Input_Data[History_Length:]
'''
```

Updated graphs for the prices and loss (For the validation dataset).
[image]

[image]

After about 6 epochs, the model loss seems to even out for both training loss and validation loss. However, this is just for Nvidia's stock. Different stocks give different results. The early stopping was an attempt to try and keep the accuracy similar between multiple stocks.

Comment: You are validating and training your data wrong. With time series you should not shuffle data, and you shouldn't use random split for train and test data, but [split on time](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350655/leave-one-out-cross-validation-for-lstm/351765#351765), whatever your cross-validation said for this model, it surely was overtly optimistic.

Comment: So in light of this, I should break up the data. If i have (currently) 1274 days worth of data, use the first (oldest dates) 75% of data for training, and the last 25% (most current dates) for validation correct? @Tim

Comment: Yes, that'd be much better for time-series data.

Comment: Alright so if I remove the validation_split from the model, and only give it the "Historical" data (oldest 75%), how would I implement using the latest 25% for validation?

Comment: So splitting the data up, I now have...  history = model.fit(x=History_Input_Data, y=History_Closing_Price, batch_size=10, epochs=50, shuffle=False, validation_data=(Validation_Input_Data, Validation_Closing_Price)), Where _Input_Data is the entire dataset, _Closing_Price is the closing price for the respective dataset. The history set is the first 75% of the entire data, and validation is the last 25% of the entire data. Now I would assume that I would use model.evaulate(Validation_Input_Data, Validation_Closing_Price)? @Tim